# How do I get Quick Books SDK to work with my Visual Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interop, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have an old C#/asp.net project that I need to edit.  It interfaces with Quick Books to create reports.  The project has a reference to Interop.QBFC11 pointing to a .dll in the GAC, but I have no such .dll in my GAC.  I did find Interop.QBFC11Lib.dll in the obj/Release folder.  I changed the reference to point to this file, but my "using Interop.QBFC11" reference threw a "could not be found" error. I looked at the .dll in JustDecompile and saw that the referenced namespace was QBFC11Lib so I added "using QBFC11Lib" to my program.  Now I have code that I need to change from "Interop.QBFC11.QBSessionManager()" to "QBFC11Lib.QBSessionManager".  I also download the latest SDK from [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0400_tools/quickbooks_desktop/download_the_sdk) and ran it.  It says it installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit, but I can't find the .dll there.  So my questions are:

1. Where can I get the version of Interop.QBFC11Lib.dll that the original programmer used?
2. If I use the Interop.QBFC11Lib.dll that I find in the obj/Release directory and rename references from Interop.QBFC11 to QBFC11Lib, will it work the same?
3. How do I get the latest Interop.QBFC11Lib.dll (or whatever the name of the most recent dll is)?

We've identified the following errors in compiling the code.  It looks like these were once part of the SDK, but aren't now.  We need help finding what new objects/methods to use:

- ENOpenMode.omDontCare not included in Interop.qbposfc3.dll or Interop.QBFC11Lib.dll
- ORInventoryAdjustmentQuery has no suitable replacements. (subclass of InventoryQtyAdjustmentQuery qry)
- ENMatchCriterion.mcContains has no suitable replacement
- ORTxnQuery has no suitable replacement (subclass of ISalesReceiptQuery qry)
- Implicit type conversion  not allowed (ISalesReceiptItemRet to ISalesReceiptRet)
- No Definitions for Desc1, Desc2, Qty, ExtendedPrice, ItemNumber (subclass of ISalesReceiptRet itemsRet)

** UPDATE **

Contacted Intuit support.  They suggested downloading files for QBFC11 and QBPOSFC3.  Tried adding references to both individually and at the same time and still getting the same errors.  Below is a screenshot.  Any ideas on how to get this to compile?

[image]

Comment: Seeing as you have a dev account with Intuit, have you tried to ask if they can help?

Comment: Not sure if we have a dev account; management is just checking into it.  I just went to their website and downloaded the latest SDK without having to login.

Comment: You said you downloaded the 'latest'. Did you scroll down further and tried downloading QBFC11 instead? (latest is 13).  Also, it installs into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks` and I can see `Interop.QBFC11.dll` there.

Comment: Yes.  I signed up for a developer account and asked Quickbooks questions, but I'm still having the problem.  They first pointed me toward the page you mentioned and downloaded the QBFC11 file.  That didn't fix the problem so they had me download a file for QBPOSFC3.  That still hasn't fixed the problem.  I've updated my question and posted a screenshot.  Any suggestions on what I can do now?

Comment: Ah, they joys of dealing with legacy code. Those are some really strange errors. I can see in my system that [ENMatchCriterion is definitely a member of Interop.QBFC11](http://i.imgur.com/bDGmQOz.png).

Comment: Also, as you can see in the screenshot - errors 1,4, and 6, there's a conflict between `QBFC11` and `qbposfc3`, both containing an enum called `ENRqOnError`.

Comment: Yes, but I've tried just having one of them and it doesn't fix the errors.  Any ideas?